# PHP multiplayer game: data synchronization doesn't work properly

Tags: php, ajax, canvas, multiplayer

I am developing a multiplayer game in PHP using Canvas and MySQL database.
Two players join the game and they first get opponent's position(X,Y and Angle). 
When they're ready, game starts. Game Algorthim goes like this. 
**Every 50 millisec**

1. Calculate their own position (X,Y)
2. Get opponent's angle(AJAX) and calculate opponents pos (X2, Y2)
3. Then draw on Canvas and update database.

   ```
   context.fillStyle = "green";
   context.fillRect(p1.x,p1.y, 5,5);
   addPoints(p1.x,p1.y);
   updateRoundJQ(p1.x,p1.y,p1.a);

   context.fillStyle = "red";
   context.fillRect(x2,y2, 5,5);
   addPoints(x2,y2);

   loopTimer = setTimeout('drawLine()', 50);
   ```

But unfortunately I get this result. There's a great delay in receiving the data. Could anyone please help me how to get rid of this great error? It would be really thankful.

**Player 1's screen**
[image: Player 1 in one computer]

**Player 2's screen**
[image: Player 2]

Comment: it seems that ajax requests screws up the whole thing. you send requests every 50milliseconds! try to raise that time , although might not be something you are comfortable doing , you can try websockets to get that "realtime" and particulary take a look at socket.io library

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I took the getAngle() and updateRound() functions outside the loop and raised the time to 10ms. The result is much better than the one above. Nevertheless the slight difference in angle produce different outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script isn't running every 50ms - as it is only setting the timeout once all the other functions have run. Depending on how `updateRound` works, this could add the time of a round trip to each interval.

For example, consider the following timings:

```
context.fillStyle = "green"; // 1ms
context.fillRect(p1.x,p1.y, 5,5); // 1ms
addPoints(p1.x,p1.y); // 1ms
updateRoundJQ(p1.x,p1.y,p1.a); // web request? 300ms

context.fillStyle = "red"; // 1ms
context.fillRect(x2,y2, 5,5); // 1ms
addPoints(x2,y2); // 1ms

loopTimer = setTimeout('drawLine()', 50); // wait 50ms from now
```

So, with these example timings, your loop will only run after ~306ms.

It may be worth considering pushing the data to your client using websockets, rather than pulling it with AJAX.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for this demonstration. That could be the issue. But I've never worked with websockets. Could you please give me a link to learn about websockets?

Comment: does Websockets support in all browsers? especially in IE?

Comment: I'm not sure - you'll have to Google it. We're getting into another question here.

Comment: I got a solution using websocket. It works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution using  **Node.JS** and  **Socket.IO**.
The solution would be much simpler than in AJAX.

```
  //Client Side Request   
  function sendMyPoints(){
       socket.emit('myPoints',p1.x,p1.y);
  }

  //Server Handles the Request 
  socket.on('myPoints',function(xP, yP){
    socket.broadcast.emit('getOppPoints',xP,yP);
  });

  //Client gets the Response
  socket.on('getOppPoints',function(xPos,yPos){
      drawOppPoints(xPos, yPos);
  });
```

Thank you for suggesting Websocket. It's awesome.